How to check if the number of samples used to build a covariance matrix is enough?
How can I determine if the number of samples used to construct a covariance matrix is enough to ensure accurate and stable estimation of the matrix?
My application is RF. I need covariance matrix to find the DOA of a signal. Is there any statistical methods or guidelines I can apply to evaluate whether the chosen sample size is adequate, thereby avoiding issues such as singularity or poor estimation of the matrix?

Look up the Reed-Mallett-Brennan rule. Essentially, the amount of IID data used to estimate the statistics should be roughly twice the amount of the system degrees of freedom, in this case, the number of antennas used to estimate DoA.

I tried using the Reed-Mallett-Brennan rule, but in my case the number of antenna is 4 and in the simulation the algorithm works really poorly.

An important factor in addition to asking if the signal is long enough is asking if the signal is too long. The improvement from the covariance will improve as long as the signal is stationary and the noise in question is sufficiently white. This assumption typically holds up well in short time durations but breaks down as observation times lengthen.
A very convenient tool for accessing the duration time for statistical noise processes is the Allan Deviation. In searching for an ADEV plot just now, I found this research article by Jun Duan and others from which I copied the graphic below, where they make this specific point about how the minimum in the Allen Deviation plot indicates the optimum integration (averaging) time for a statistical process. This would translate to the optimum sample size for the covariance matrix in that the related estimates would improve or degrade according to the vertical axis of the ADEV plot as the total time duration involved is changed.

The Allan Deviation is most often used in the assessment of the long term frequency stability of oscillators and the bias stability of gyroscopes given that both of these processes are non-stationary in relatively short time intervals. However the processing can be applied to any random signal for purposes of optimum integration time, covariance time, FFT block size, equalizer time span, etc as I have further detailed in these other related posts:
How do I determine stationarity from a set of 50 complex values collected every 10 minutes?
Allan Variance vs Autocorrelation - Advantages
How to interpret Allan Deviation plot for gyroscope?
What determines the accuracy of the phase result in a DFT bin?
Usefulness of Allan deviation with DC signals
Is Allan variance still relevant?
Averaging data from 2 sensors
Usefulness of Allan deviation with DC signals
